# elementary matrices over a regular ring

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 3$. Let $A$ be a regular ring and $\gamma\in GL_{n}(A)$. We suppose that $\gamma$ is homotopic to the identity, i.e. there exists $\alpha\in GL_{n}(A[X])$ such that $\alpha(0)=\gamma$ and $\alpha(1)=I_{n}$.

Can we prove that $\gamma\in E_{n}(A)$, the group generated by elementary matrices?
It is known if $n$ is big enough depending on the dimension of the ring, but a sharper bound should hold.